# Deleting data on BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, where-clause, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete multiple inactive customer IDs in a table so that I could join it with other tables. I've used this query to achieve my goal:

```
DELETE FROM `MY-PROJECT.google_ads1.p_Customer_2670156874` 
WHERE ExternalCustomerId = 2370433843
AND ExternalCustomerId = 7411145258
```

However, it says that "This statement removed 0 rows(...)" when I know that there are at least 3 rows for each ID. It works when I delete it one by one, but that would be time consuming in the long run. Any suggestions? Thank you!

AK

Comment: Try it as `SELECT` does it give you the right results?

Comment: Use OR instead of AND. ID cannot have both values at the same time, that is why

Comment: There is two ways you can get desired Output using below Where clause:

1) WHERE ExternalCustomerId IN (2370433843,7411145258)
2) WHERE ExternalCustomerId  = 2370433843 or ExternalCustomerId   = 7411145258

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `IN` operator to specify multiple values in a `WHERE` clause.

Using this sample data:

[image]

I ran this query to delete `ExternalCustomerId` rows with `2370433843` and `7411145258` values:

```
DELETE 
FROM `myproject.mydataset.cust_table`
WHERE ExternalCustomerId IN (2370433843,7411145258)
```

Result:

[image]

Rows were deleted successfully and the table ended up with this data:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can get desired Output using below Where clause:

1. WHERE ExternalCustomerId IN (2370433843,7411145258)
2. WHERE ExternalCustomerId  = 2370433843 or ExternalCustomerId   = 7411145258